# Spring Cloud AWS SQS AccessDenied

Tags: spring, cloud, messaging, amazon-sqs, access-denied

I am currently having a connection issue trying to connect to an AWS SQS Queue using Spring Cloud and Spring Boot.  I believe I have everything configured fine but am getting:

> 2015-07-01 18:12:11,926 [WARN][-]
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[487]
>   - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
>   start bean 'simpleMessageListenerContainer'; nested exception is
>   com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Access to the resource
>   https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{Number}/{Queue Name} is denied.
>   (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
>   Request ID: 87312428-ec0f-5990-9f69-6a269a041b4d)

```
@Configuration
@EnableSqs
public class CloudConfiguration {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CloudConfiguration.class);

    @MessageMapping("QUEUE")
    public void retrieveProvisionMessages(User user) {
        log.warn(user.firstName);
    }
}
```

YML

```
cloud:
    aws:
       credentials.accessKey: AccessKey
       credentials.secretKey: SecretKey
       region.static: us-west-2
       credentials.instanceProfile: true
```

When it attempts to connect I see that a header value of:

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=accesskey/20150701/us-west-2/sqs/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;user-agent;x-amz-date, Signature=signature
```

After the request is sent:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [Server: Server, Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 22:51:25 GMT, Content-Type: text/xml, Content-Length: 349, Connection: keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId: Request Id] org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@37e55df6
```

I have checked all AIM policies and they are correct.

Using:

```
private AmazonSQS establishQueue(){
    AmazonSQS sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
    sqs.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion(region));
    return sqs;
}


    AmazonSQS sqs = establishQueue();
    return sqs.receiveMessage(sqs.getQueueUrl(userProductPurchase).getQueueUrl());
```

with the same credentials works fine.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Do you have `GetQueueAttributes` calls allowed for your IAM user?

I think it's using also few more operations. Not only `ReceiveMessage` and `GetQueueUrl`.

Comment: Yes I have completely opened up all access while testing.  Again using the AWS SDK everything works fine, just can't connect with the Spring Cloud components.

Comment: Can you try `GetQueueAttributes` with AWS SDK too? I don't think you can get access denied when everything is allowed.

Comment: This solved my problem :D i thought receive messages permission was enough

Answer (score 4):

In my case, using Spring Cloud, I had to set the following permissions up:

- `sqs:DeleteMessage`
- `sqs:GetQueueUrl`
- `sqs:ReceiveMessage`
- `sqs:SendMessage`
- `sqs:GetQueueAttributes`